# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'company.Something.AssemblyName

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, .net, assembly-references

I have a class library A which has a dll reference B (class library). And they are using same .NET framework 3.5

When I call project B's method `something()` from project A, It is throwing an exception:

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'company.Something.AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2fc3806c28fa11fb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Sometimes it throws:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load file or assembly.

I deleted dll from GAC and copied it from bin folder, but it didn't work.

Build configuration is set it `Any CPU` in both class library's.